# Nested Form in Rails don't show nothing in Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create a nested form with relations between Clientes has_many enderecos, but in my form nothing is show up.

Look my models:

```
class Cliente < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enderecos, dependent: :destroy

  validates :nome, :sexo, presence: true
  validates :cpf, :email, :username, presence:true, uniqueness: true
  has_secure_password 

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :enderecos
end
```

And endereco:

```
class Endereco < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cliente
end
```

And my form:

```
<%= form_for(@cliente) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :nome, placeholder: 'Nome completo', size: '50px' %>
  </div>

  <% f.fields_for :endereco do |endereco_form| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= endereco_form.label :cep, 'placeholder: ' %>
        <%= endereco_form.text_field :cep, placeholder: 'CEP' %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= endereco_form.text_field :numero, placeholder: 'Número' %>
      </div>

  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But inside nested part nothing is show up, what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the '=' sign:

```
<%= f.fields_for :endereco do |endereco_form| %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe this